# Writing to Remote FileShare Location using Log4Net

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, transformation, rollingfileappender

I have a .net web.config transformation file in which I have specified a remote file share in which I want my rolling file appender to write to. Initially I specified that default App_Data/Logs as the location and this worked fine. When I used the remote file location, it does not work. Is it even possible to write to a remote file share location solely using .NETs web.config transformations?

```
\\[FILE_SHARE_IP_ADDRESS]\directory1\directory2\directory3\directory4
```

Comment: what if You use double slashes ? like \\\\FILE_SHARE_IP_ADDRESS]\\directory1\\...

Comment: Nope, no luck. That did not work.

Comment: Slash at the end?  Copy paste to make sure there's no mistype. Make sure process runs under account that has permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, almost all file logging I use writes to a remote file share using the standard log4net appender and the syntax you've got above.

99 times out of 100 that I encounter file logging failures the problem is permissions. Make sure the user account your code runs under has access to that remote share.

You could also try switching on log4net diagnostics to see if any errors are being logged.

Comment: thudbutt, your tip about turning on the log4net diagnostics was really helpful. It shows the following error: log4net:ERROR [FnfCustomRollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Unable to acquire lock on file "[LOG FILE LOCATION]" . The account used is a computer account. Use your global user account or local user account to access this server. So it seems to be related to a permissions issue as well as a file lock issue. What would be your recommendation.

Comment: You will need to grant read/write access for the remote file share to the user the website/service is running under. The error suggests that the site/service is running under a default app pool account or Network Service account and you may need to change to a local or domain account to grant the appropriate access.